# Print NSString Argument using NSLog

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring, nslog

```
-(void) postToDB:(NSString*) msg{
    //print msg
    NSString *myphp = @"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/databases/test.php";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myphp];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:msg forKey:@"message"];
}
```

In the above method, how can I print 'msg' using NSLog?

Many thanks

Comment: The format specifier for any object is `%@` (including `NSString`)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`NSLog(@"%@",msg);` its of type NSString.

Comment: i got this result on my console: <CDVInvokedUrlCommand: 0x1753c130>
Where i fail??

Answer (score 8):

Using This

```
NSLog(@"Message == %@",msg);
```

Answer (score 3):

You will like this:

```
#define CNMLog(msg) NSLog(@"%@", msg)
CNMLog(msg);
```